# Is Approaching haraam is like done it

Tags: sin

I have read in a website that if a man approaches a haram deed like, “Zina” but fails, then he is considered as he has done it even if penetration does not occur.

If so, is he considers a zani and send to Heaven. On the other hand , it is famous in Islam that if a man has thought about haram then he is not cursed. 
Is there, is so then, the man how approach zina but fail to do it. Is this person punished in this world and also in hereafter. If he repent sincerely then he will be forgiven by Allah???

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if this is a good answer, but take a look:

God Said:

> Surah Az-Zumar Verse 53
>   “Say: O My slaves who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah, verily, Allah forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” (Surah Az-Zumar 39:53)
>
> Allah says in the Holy Quran Chapter 39 Surah Zumur verses 53-54:
>   (O Prophet) say: O My servants who have wronged their own souls.Do not despair of Allahs Mercy! Surely, Allah forgives all sins. He indeed is the All Forgiving, All Merciful. Return to your Lord and submit to Him before the scourge overtakes you; for then you may get no help from anywhere.
>
> “Whatever of good reaches you, is from Allah, but whatever of evil befalls you, is from yourself…”
>   [al-Nisa 4:79]
>
> “Indeed Allah loves those who repent and purify themselves.“ [Surah Al Baqarah, 2:222]
>
> O child of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind. O child of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you.
>
> Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.  (Sûrat Al-Nisâ’, 4:27].
>
> Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.  (Sûrat Al-Nisâ’, 4:27].
>
> The Prophet œ told us of a man who will come on the Day of Judgment and will be shown his minor sins, his major ones being hidden from him. He cannot deny all the messed up things he had done and he’s worried about seeing even bigger sins he had committed than those he’s being shown. Then it is said: Replace every bad deed with a good one! And the man says, “My Lord! I did other messed up stuff that isn’t written in here!” And the Prophet œ laughed when he relayed this man’s reaction. (Bukhâri)
>
> On the Day We will say to Hell, "Have you been filled?" and it will say, "Are there some more,"(Surat Qāf,verse 30)
>   And:
>   ... "I will surely fill Hell with jinn and people all together.'"(Surat As-Sajdah,verse 13)
>
> Every soul will taste death. And We test you with evil and with good as trial; and to Us you will be returned.
>
> “Whatever of good reaches you, is from Allah, but whatever of evil befalls you, is from yourself…”
>   [al-Nisa 4:79]
>
> Allah also says (interpretation of the meaning): “And whatever of misfortune befalls you, it is because of what your hands have earned. And He pardons much.”
>
> Ibn Katheer, may Allah have mercy on him, said: “[It means] whatever misfortune happens to you, O people, is because of evil deeds that you have already done, and ‘He pardons much’ refers to evil deeds – He does not punish you for them but He pardons them. ‘And if Allah were to punish men for that which they earned, he would not leave a moving (living) creature on the surface of the earth…’ [Fatir 35:45 – interpretation of the meaning].”
>   [al-Shoora 42:30]

**CONCLUSION:**  If the man did not approached the haram thing, will not be Punished. And if he asks sincere forgiveness, if God wish, will forgive him. And, if a man did something sinful he might get punished by God in this world, but if He does not want to and He Punish him in Hereafter, then, it will happen.